# set audience when posting on friend's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook, target-audience

I am having feature in my app where user can post on his/her friends's wall. I have added this feature and it will display dialog to user to post. But I want to set audience to me and that user only using code. But I am not able to do so.

Can we set audience while posting on friends wall ? If yes then please show me a way to do so.

I tried to search but couldn't find anything related to setting audience while posting on friends wall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the audience when posting to a friend's wall.  The friend controls the content on their wall, thus you cannot set the audience.  You could post to your own wall and set the audience to just you and your friend though.

Comment: I assumed that this is the case. But I couldn't find a official document which says this. If you have a link of official document where they say the same then please give a link. it would be great. thanks.

Comment: Can't find any specific document about it but did find this in our help guide.  https://www.facebook.com/help/173433019380025